# 301 Redirect to homepage returning a 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I found a website linking to my site with `www.example.com/home.html` which doesn't exist. I tried to set up a redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /home.html //www.example.com
```

But it redirects to `www.example.com/www.mysite.com`

Can I use the `Redirect`, or do I have to do a rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

please use rewrite rule:

first:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
```

and then

```
 RewriteRule ^home.html$ http://www.example.com/ [r=301,nc,L]
```

Comment: Does this need to be inbetween opening and closing tags such as: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>. I'm testing the above locally but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @brandozz No other line or filter is required to redirect  `http://example.com/home.html` to `http://www.example.com/`. It must work in the net. make sure no other rules contradict this rule.

Answer (score 0):

> `Redirect 301 /home.html //www.example.com`

In this case, the target URL (starting with a slash) is seen to be root-relative to the current scheme/host. Providing you have a `DirectoryIndex` setup appropriately, you can just redirect to `/`.

For example:

```
Redirect 301 /home.html /
```